Is "beginnerness" a valid word?
Today, I used the word beginnerness in a sentence like so:

I did not use C++ for ages, plus I was never much good at it, so please excuse my beginnerness.


Intended meaning:

I am a person, who is still begining with the C++ (programming language).


I originally though it would be ok to use like that, but I found it (almost) nowhere to be seen or even found in the search engine (which I used at least), Google Translator goes haywire upon giving it this word, and provides me with a plural of one beginner.

But, just before posting this question, I have found (to me an unknown) DeepL translator, which surprisingly provides the exact meaning of the word expressed in my language. Let me attach a direct link, please, I am Czech language native. (It could be interesting to know if it translates my word correctly to other languages too, but that is not what I ask here.):
https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/cs/beginnerness

So, now I think it could be an unused word, maybe even in a category of unofficial / informal English? Can you please confirm/disprove?
Thank you in advance!

There is no such word, but if there was, it would be beginnerliness. Consider I am a man. I hope you like my manliness (there's no such word as manness either).

@FumbleFingers Thank you for your advice. I have already changed the word in favor of inexperience as advised here. Cheers!

It's understandable but not completely cromulent. The "-ness" suffix is fairly freely added to adjectives.  It can be added to nouns in an casual way to produce one-off words meaning "The state of being an X".  Wiktionary gives the examples of "treeness" and "thugness".
But these are unlikely to be found in paper dictionaries, and often there is a better way to express the same idea. Here you could simply replace "beginerness" with "inexperience".

There are lots of synonyms once you have a good word to look up like "inexperience":  "rawness", "newness", "freshness", "unfamiliarity", "incognizance", "nescience", some more negative or formal than others.

@StuartF Ok, thanks. I don't know some of these words. I will better avoid my word, and replace it. Cheers

Or please excuse the fact that I am a beginner.

Maybe I should have noted, that for some reason, I really liked that beginnerness word. It sounded strangely good to me, which is why I asked in the first place. Anyway, I've already said my goodbyes to that word. So, case solved for me. But, feel free to add more answers for future readers to choose what is best for them!

In a context where the speaker is having a bit of fun with those whom he’s addressing, beginnerness as you have used it would be fine. But bear in mind that from the mouth of a native speaker, it would definitely suggest self-conscious quirkiness. And if a nonnative speaker used it, most Anglophones would assume that it was a mistake rather than an intentional bit of whimsy.
A completely idiomatic—indeed somewhat formal—alternative is please excuse my being a beginner. And if what you intended to emphasize  were the length of time since you had written any C++ rather than the brevity of your use, you could substitute in the word rustiness for beginnerness.

Thank you for a nice addition! Upvoted both.

No, it wouldn't be fine. Per my comment under the question, any such noun-derived abstract quality would be beginnerliness, not beginnerness.

Here, @FumbleFingers, we arrive at the subjective. One native speaker (you) says, “No, it’s not okay,” while another (me) says, “Yes, it is fine. Artificial and quirky, but fine in a playful register.” And neither of us can claim to possess any objectively factual decree.

Well, I suppose that's true. But I certainly wouldn't advise learners to copy the natives in this area.

There, @FumbleFingers, we are in complete agreement. And that’s why my answer advises, “If a nonnative speaker used it, most Anglophones would assume that it was a mistake rather than an intentional bit of whimsy.”
